# why cleanup function dos not work in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

timer dos not stop after we go into another component and then loser component will runing
but i can see unmounted in console. i mean want to cleanup timer function like componentWillUnmount in class components.

```js
    function timeDown() {
        if (stepName == 'question') {
            let haveTime = state.haveTime;
            let time = setInterval(() => {
                haveTime -= 1;
                setState({ haveTime })
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(() => {
                clearInterval(time)
                dispatch(getNameStep(states.step))
            }, 60000);
  } else {
    return
  }
}
useEffect(() => {
    timeDown()
    return () => {
      console.log('unmounted')
      timeDown()
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: Hey Mahdi, welcome to SO. I am not sure if I understand your question. It usually helps to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e.g. on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Answer (score 1):

`time` is not a timeout but an interval:

`clearTimeout(time)` ⇨ `clearInterval(time)`

Answer (score 0):

There's two kinds of "timer" functions. `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`. Note that each of these have their respective `clear` functions.

When you make a timer using `setInterval()`, you must clear it with `clearInterval()`, same for `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()`.

`time`, in your example, is an interval. The following code should work:

```
function timeDown() {
  if (stepName == 'question') {
    let haveTime = state.haveTime;
    let time = setInterval(() => {
        haveTime -= 1;
        setState({ haveTime })
      }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(time)
        dispatch(getNameStep(states.step))
      }, 60000);
  } else {
    return
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
    timeDown()
    return () => {
      console.log('unmounted')
      timeDown()
    }
  }, [])
```